# Fit table on a page

Tags: tables, scaling

I have the following large table:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[p]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Robustness I \label{table6}}
\begin{tabular}{ll*{6}{c}}
\toprule \toprule
                    &&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}\\
\midrule \noalign{\medskip}
$y_{i,t}$            & &       -0.100\sym{***} &        0.897\sym{***}&        0.892\sym{***}&        0.903\sym{***}&        0.905\sym{***}&        0.927\sym{***}\\
                    &&      (0.031) &      (0.032)         &      (0.031)         &      (0.032)         &      (.030)         &      (0.031)                 \\
$PC_{i,t}$                 &&       -0.125\sym{***} &       -0.118\sym{***}&       -0.138\sym{***}&       -0.116\sym{***}&       -0.126\sym{***}&       -0.082\sym{**} \\
                    &&      (0.041)  &      (0.041)         &      (0.042)         &      (0.041)         &      (.041)         &      (0.038)                \\
$PC^{2}_{i,t}$              &&        0.013\sym{***}   &        0.012\sym{***}&        0.014\sym{***}&        0.012\sym{***}&        0.013\sym{***}&        0.009\sym{***}\\
                    &&      (0.004) &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)                  \\
$(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$            &&        0.157\sym{***}&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
                   &&      (0.061) &                     &                     &                     &                     &                              \\
$(ln)s_{i,t}$           & &     &        0.149\sym{**} &                     &                     &                     &                                         \\
                    &  &&      (0.062)         &                     &                     &                     &                                          \\
$(ln)(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$       &  & &       -0.249         &                     &                     &                     &                                         \\
                    & &&      (0.154)         &                     &                     &                     &                                          \\
$(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta+g_{T})_{i,t}$             &&  &                     &        0.175\sym{***}&                     &                     &                                          \\
                   & & &                     &      (0.065)         &                     &                     &                                       \\
$(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta_{0.03}+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$            & & &                     &                     &        0.140\sym{**} &                     &                                         \\
                   & &  &                     &                     &      (0.058)         &                     &                                         \\
$(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta_{0.07}+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$           & & &                     &                     &                     &        0.152\sym{**} &                                        \\
                    & &&                     &                     &                     &      (0.060)         &                                       \\
$(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{EF})_{i,t}$             & & &                     &                     &                     &                     &        0.083\sym{*}                     \\
                    & &&                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.050)                             \\

\midrule
Observations                                & &670                      &670                    &         681         &         670         &         670         &         668                 \\[1ex]
N. of Groups                                    & &118                      &118                 &         119         &         118         &         118         &         116                   \\[1ex]
AR1                                             &&[0.000]                &[0.000]            &[0.000]             &[0.000]             &[0.000]             &[0.000]                                                           \\[1ex]
AR2                                             &&[0.324]  & [0.362]                &[0.364]           &[0.347]                     & [0.341]                    &[0.182]                                                             \\[1ex]
Hansen Test                                 && [0.236]  &[0.246]                    &[0.247]            &[0.241]                     &[0.221]                     &[0.131]                                                           \\[1ex]
Hansen--in--difference Test     &&[0.875]  &[0.904]                 &[0.855]                     &[0.857]             &[0.868]                     & [0.771]                                                              \\[1ex]
\midrule
Extremum Point&                       & 4.970&4.996                         &5.007                 &4.955                     &4.963                     &4.384                                                               \\[.5ex]
&Mimimum                                  &-0.100&-0.094                        &-0.110                   &-0.092 &-0.101&-0.063\\[1ex]
&                                                 &[0.001&[0.002]                        &[0.001]                 &[0.003]&[0.001&[0.022]]\\[1ex]
&Maximum                                      &0.127&0.118                           &0.137                   &0.118&0.128&0.105\\[1ex]
&                                             &[0.001]&[0.002]                       &[0.000]                 &[0.001]&[0.001]&[0.002]\\[1ex]
$t$--test (overall)&                      &3.02&2.85                            &3.21                         &2.77&3.05&2.02\\
                              &                   &[0.001]&[0.002]                      &[0.001]                      &[0.003]&[0.001]&[0.021]\\
Fieller interval     &                 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.152}{5.710}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.107}{5.943}$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.311}{5.541}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{3.938}{5.715}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.152}{5.693}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{1.334}{5.407}$} \\[1ex]

\bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
      \item[]{\textit{Notes}: The GMM--SYS has been used to obtain all the estimates reported in the Table. Refer to Notes to Tables 3 and 5 for a deeper explanation of the lags used in the analysis and of the reported tests. 
      ***, ** and * denote significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level. Geographic and period dummies included but not reported. Robust standard errors in brackets.}
      \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

I import it into another LaTeX file where I include the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[scale=1,textheight=27cm, textwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{interval}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\input{tab1.tex}
\end{document}
```

The table is larger than the page, therefore I tried to rescale it using different approaches:

1. I included in the table file:

   ```
   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{sidewaystable}[p]
   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
   \centering
   \normalsize
   \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
   \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption{Robustness I \label{table6}}
   \begin{tabular}{ll*{6}{c}}
   \toprule \toprule
                       &&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}\\
   \midrule \noalign{\medskip}
   $y_{i,t}$            & &       -0.100\sym{***} &        0.897\sym{***}&        0.892\sym{***}&        0.903\sym{***}&        0.905\sym{***}&        0.927\sym{***}\\
                       &&      (0.031) &      (0.032)         &      (0.031)         &      (0.032)         &      (.030)         &      (0.031)                 \\
   $PC_{i,t}$                 &&       -0.125\sym{***} &       -0.118\sym{***}&       -0.138\sym{***}&       -0.116\sym{***}&       -0.126\sym{***}&       -0.082\sym{**} \\
                       &&      (0.041)  &      (0.041)         &      (0.042)         &      (0.041)         &      (.041)         &      (0.038)                \\
   $PC^{2}_{i,t}$              &&        0.013\sym{***}   &        0.012\sym{***}&        0.014\sym{***}&        0.012\sym{***}&        0.013\sym{***}&        0.009\sym{***}\\
                       &&      (0.004) &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)         &      (0.004)                  \\
   $(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$            &&        0.157\sym{***}&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
                      &&      (0.061) &                     &                     &                     &                     &                              \\
   $(ln)s_{i,t}$           & &     &        0.149\sym{**} &                     &                     &                     &                                         \\
                       &  &&      (0.062)         &                     &                     &                     &                                          \\
   $(ln)(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$       &  & &       -0.249         &                     &                     &                     &                                         \\
                       & &&      (0.154)         &                     &                     &                     &                                          \\
   $(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta+g_{T})_{i,t}$             &&  &                     &        0.175\sym{***}&                     &                     &                                          \\
                      & & &                     &      (0.065)         &                     &                     &                                       \\
   $(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta_{0.03}+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$            & & &                     &                     &        0.140\sym{**} &                     &                                         \\
                      & &  &                     &                     &      (0.058)         &                     &                                         \\
   $(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta_{0.07}+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$           & & &                     &                     &                     &        0.152\sym{**} &                                        \\
                       & &&                     &                     &                     &      (0.060)         &                                       \\
   $(ln)s_{i,t}-ln(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{EF})_{i,t}$             & & &                     &                     &                     &                     &        0.083\sym{*}                     \\
                       & &&                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.050)                             \\

   \midrule
   Observations                                & &670                      &670                    &         681         &         670         &         670         &         668                 \\[1ex]
   N. of Groups                                    & &118                      &118                 &         119         &         118         &         118         &         116                   \\[1ex]
   AR1                                             &&[0.000]                &[0.000]            &[0.000]             &[0.000]             &[0.000]             &[0.000]                                                           \\[1ex]
   AR2                                             &&[0.324]  & [0.362]                &[0.364]           &[0.347]                     & [0.341]                    &[0.182]                                                             \\[1ex]
   Hansen Test                                 && [0.236]  &[0.246]                    &[0.247]            &[0.241]                     &[0.221]                     &[0.131]                                                           \\[1ex]
   Hansen--in--difference Test     &&[0.875]  &[0.904]                 &[0.855]                     &[0.857]             &[0.868]                     & [0.771]                                                              \\[1ex]
   \midrule
   Extremum Point&                       & 4.970&4.996                         &5.007                 &4.955                     &4.963                     &4.384                                                               \\[.5ex]
   &Mimimum                                  &-0.100&-0.094                        &-0.110                   &-0.092 &-0.101&-0.063\\[1ex]
   &                                                 &[0.001&[0.002]                        &[0.001]                 &[0.003]&[0.001&[0.022]]\\[1ex]
   &Maximum                                      &0.127&0.118                           &0.137                   &0.118&0.128&0.105\\[1ex]
   &                                             &[0.001]&[0.002]                       &[0.000]                 &[0.001]&[0.001]&[0.002]\\[1ex]
   $t$--test (overall)&                      &3.02&2.85                            &3.21                         &2.77&3.05&2.02\\
                                 &                   &[0.001]&[0.002]                      &[0.001]                      &[0.003]&[0.001]&[0.021]\\
   Fieller interval     &                 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.152}{5.710}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.107}{5.943}$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.311}{5.541}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{3.938}{5.715}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{4.152}{5.693}$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\interval{1.334}{5.407}$} \\[1ex]

   \bottomrule\bottomrule
   \end{tabular}}
   \begin{tablenotes}
   \footnotesize
         \item[]{\textit{Notes}: The GMM--SYS has been used to obtain all the estimates reported in the Table. Refer to Notes to Tables 3 and 5 for a deeper explanation of the lags used in the analysis and of the reported tests. 
         ***, ** and * denote significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level. Geographic and period dummies included but not reported. Robust standard errors in brackets.}
         \end{tablenotes}
   \end{threeparttable}
   \end{sidewaystable}
   ```
2. I tried to use the package `adjustbox` in the preamble of the file where I import the table and in the table file I wrote just before `\begin{tabular}`:

   ```
   \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
   ```

I also include `\end{adjustbox}` after `\end{tabular}`.

None of them work. Any hints?

Comment: Guys, I have done. \end{adjustbox} should go at the very end just before \end{sidewaystable}

Comment: If you fixed it please consider deleting your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP seems to have solved it himself (see comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\adjustbox` unless you like swinging a sledgehammer in a china shop and don't care whether your readers will even attempt to decipher what's in the table. Do align the numbers on the respective decimal markers: your readers will thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\newgeometry{a4paper,margin=1.5cm} % narrower margins
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\small
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Robustness I \label{table6}}
\begin{tabular}{l *{6}{d{2.5}} }
\toprule
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)}\\
\midrule
$y_{i,t}$ & -0.100\sym{***} & 0.897\sym{***} & 0.892\sym{***} & 0.903\sym{***}& 0.905\sym{***} & 0.927\sym{***}\\
              & (0.031) & (0.032) & (0.031) & (0.032) & (.030) & (0.031) \\
$PC_{i,t}$ & -0.125\sym{***} & -0.118\sym{***}& -0.138\sym{***}& -0.116\sym{***}& -0.126\sym{***}& -0.082\sym{**} \\
              & (0.041) & (0.041) & (0.042) & (0.041) & (.041) & (0.038) \\
$PC^{2}_{i,t}$ & 0.013\sym{***} & 0.012\sym{***}& 0.014\sym{***}& 0.012\sym{***}& 0.013\sym{***}& 0.009\sym{***}\\
              & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\[0.75ex]
$\ln s_{i,t}-\ln(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$ & 0.157\sym{***} \\
 & (0.061) \\
$\ln s_{i,t}$ & & 0.149\sym{**} \\
              & & (0.062) \\
$\ln (n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$ & & -0.249 \\
              & & (0.154) \\
$\ln s_{i,t}-\ln(n+\delta+g_{T})_{i,t}$ & & & 0.175\sym{***}& & & \\
              & & & (0.065) & & & \\
$\ln s_{i,t}-\ln(n+\delta_{0.03}+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$ & & & & 0.140\sym{**} & & \\
              & & & & (0.058) & & \\
$\ln s_{i,t}-\ln(n+\delta_{0.07}+g_{T}+g_{GLOB})_{i,t}$ & & & & & 0.152\sym{**} & \\
              & & & & & (0.060) & \\
$\ln s_{i,t}-\ln(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{EF})_{i,t}$ & & & & & & 0.083\sym{*} \\
              & & & & & & (0.050) \\

\midrule
Observations &\mc{670} &\mc{670} & \mc{681} & \mc{670} & \mc{670} & \mc{668} \\
N.\ of Groups &\mc{118} &\mc{118} & \mc{119} & \mc{118} & \mc{118} & \mc{116} \\
AR1 &[0.000] &[0.000] &[0.000] &[0.000] &[0.000] &[0.000] \\
AR2 &[0.324] & [0.362] &[0.364] &[0.347] & [0.341] &[0.182] \\
Hansen Test & [0.236] &[0.246] &[0.247] &[0.241] &[0.221] & [0.131] \\
Hansen-in-difference Test &[0.875] &[0.904] &[0.855] &[0.857] &[0.868] & [0.771] \\
\midrule
Extremum Point & 4.970&4.996 &5.007 &4.955 &4.963 &4.384 \\
\quad Minimum & -0.100&-0.094 &-0.110 &-0.092 &-0.101&-0.063\\
 &[0.001&[0.002] &[0.001] &[0.003]&[0.001]&[0.022]\\
\quad Maximum &0.127&0.118 &0.137 &0.118&0.128&0.105\\
 &[0.001]&[0.002] &[0.000] &[0.001]&[0.001]&[0.002]\\
$t$--test (overall) &3.02&2.85 &3.21 &2.77&3.05&2.02\\
 & [0.001]&[0.002] &[0.001] &[0.003]&[0.001]&[0.021]\\
Fieller interval &\mc{$\interval{4.152}{5.710}$} &\mc{$\interval{4.107}{5.943}$} 
                 &\mc{$\interval{4.311}{5.541}$} &\mc{$\interval{3.938}{5.715}$} 
                 &\mc{$\interval{4.152}{5.693}$} &\mc{$\interval{1.334}{5.407}$} \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
  \item[]{\textit{Notes}: GMM--SYS has been used to obtain all the 
  estimates reported in the Table. Refer to Notes to Tables 3 and 5 
  for a deeper explanation of the lags used in the analysis and of the 
  reported tests.
  ***, ** and * denote significance at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% levels. 
  Geographic and period dummies included but not reported. Robust 
  standard errors in brackets.}
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```